# read char from file

Tags: c, file, fgetc

I would like to know why my program gets wrong result. I just need to read characters from file including white space, (.), (,), and others and output them in particular string format.
As a result I get more 300 instances of char read and their weird representation.I need to print the actual character and it's memory location. Appreciate it!

```
 34 instances of character :
 35 instances of character ¼
 36 instances of character ¼
 37 instances of character ¼

  #include <stdio.h>

  int main()
  {
   char ch;
   int characters[100];
   int i,j,k;
   int charCount = 0;

   FILE *fPtr;
   fPtr=fopen("input.txt", "r");

   while(ch = fgetc(fPtr) != EOF)
   {
     i=0;
     characters[i] = (char)ch;
     i++;
   }

   int arrayLength = sizeof(characters)/sizeof(characters[0]);

   for(j= 0; j < arrayLength; j++)
   {
     for(k=1; k < arrayLength; k++)
     {
       if(characters[j] == characters[k])
   {
      charCount++;
          printf("%d instances of character %c in location %c \n", charCount, characters[j], &characters[j]);
   }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: `while(ch = fgetc(fPtr) != EOF)` - er, operator precedence, shouldn't "ch = fgetc(fPtr)" be in parentheses?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Also, you're not watching for NULL, so you're analyzing the entire block of memory regardless of how much you actually write.

Comment: `location %c` -> `location %p`

Answer (score 1):

Remember this:  `fgetch()` returns `int`. Not `char`. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc).

This is because the `EOF` constant is larger than a character, so there has to be more bits in the return value to be able to express "any character, or `EOF`".

In other words, `EOF` is not a character, it's an example of [out-of-band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band) communications.

Also, your parenthesis look odd, you probably mean:

```
while((ch = fgetc(fPtr)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
```

Note inner parenthesis around the assignment, only.

Comment: Also, you're reinitting `i` i to 0 in every iteration of thewhile loop.

Comment: @H2CO3 Shouldn't this comment belong in the question's comments section?